# Euclidean metric on the Riemann Sphere

Tags: metric-spaces, spherical-geometry

I'm finally working my way through Sarason's *Complex Function Theory*.

The mapping from the complex plane into the sphere has the rule:
$$
z \mapsto \frac{(2 \operatorname{Re} z,2\operatorname{Im}z, |z|^2-1)}{|z|^2+1}.
$$
Let $\rho(z_1,z_2)$ denote the Euclidean distance between two points on the sphere. Show that the corresponding metric on the complex plane $\mathbb{C}$ is:
$$
\mu(z_1,z_2)=\frac{2|z_1-z_2|}{\sqrt{|z_1|^2 +1}\sqrt{|z_2|^2 +1}}
$$
I think I could establish this equivalence by using:
$$
z_1=x_1+iy_1\\
z_2=x_2+iy_2 \\
|z_1-z_2|=\sqrt{(x_1-x_2)^2+(y_1-y_2)^2}
$$
and lots of algebra.  Is there a simpler way to establish this metric?

It seems like it's easy enough to show
$$
\mu(z_1,z_2)\ge 0, \text{with equality if }z_1=z_2 \\
\mu(z_1,z_2)=\mu(z_2,z_1)\\
\mu(z_1,z_2) + \mu(z_2,z_3) \ge \mu(z_1,z_3)
$$
Still, I'd like to understand more deeply what it means for the two metrics to be equivalent.

Comment: I know that two metrics are equivalent if they "yield the same families of open sets", but i'd like a deeper understanding.  After all $\rho(x_1,x_2)$ is defined on $X$ and $\mu(y_1,y_2)$ could be defined on $Y$, perhaps two very different metric spaces.